# cd into directory using multiple variables from back script

Tags: bash

This script appears useless I know but I'm testing for a final variant.  When I call `cd` using multiple variables.  Nothing happens.  However, when I `echo ${this}${that}` it produces the proper text.  What do I need to do to drop into the directory correctly from a bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash

this=/path/to
that=/final/directory

echo ${this}${that}
cd ${this}${that}
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo "[${this}][${that}]` ? If there's some spaces or newlines, you need to quotes variables!

Comment: @GillesQuénot `/path/to/final/directory`
that's why I'm here, I don't understand why the echo produces the correct outcome but the cd does nothing.

Comment: This is your problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367512/cd-with-variable-not-working. Still looking for a Stackoverflow dupe ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `echo $PWD` after the `cd`, and you'll see that your `cd` does work. But the script runs in its own shell, and when that shell exits, you're back where you came from.

So you can `cd` somewhere and do work there as long as you're in the same script. Any program called from your script after the `cd` will also run in the directory you `cd`'d to.